# Add item to databound DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist control  where item lists are coming from database

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="semester" 
        DataValueField="semester">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

But I want to add at the beginning 1 list item more "ALL" .. How can I add this one .

Thanks !

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of this question? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679128/add-empty-item-to-dropdownlist-of-custom-objects-in-c

Answer (score 19):

To add a new list item to the DropDownList, in the Properties window, click on the ellipses in the Items property.
Add a new list item with Text "ALL" & Value -1.

Or you can add the list item by adding this markup to the DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="categories" runat="server" ...>
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">
       ALL
    </asp:ListItem>         
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Set the DropDownList's `AppendDataBoundItems=True`

Comment: Yeah, omitting that could really mystify you, eh?

Answer (score 5):

With Items.Insert method you can add an item at a specific index :

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("ALL", "ALL"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to disable the `viewstate` of `DropDownList1` so that it doesn't retain each `resultset` from the db!