# Add extra option to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net dropdown list that populates from a sqldatasource. My issue is that the first option needs to be (All). Is there anyway to add this extra option to the list before the eqldatasource list?

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="REGIONS" runat="server" 
      Width="70px"  AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="REGION_CD" 
      DataValueField="REGION_CD" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  >
     </asp:DropDownList>

     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION %>" 
      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION.ProviderName %>" 
      SelectCommand="select distinct(region_cd) from mv_gauge_filter_dist where     region_cd is not null">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thanx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679128/add-empty-item-to-dropdownlist-of-custom-objects-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but this should work:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="REGIONS" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" 
  Width="70px"  AutoPostBack="True" DataTextField="REGION_CD" 
  DataValueField="REGION_CD" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  >
  <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="" />
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION %>" 
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PRODUCTION.ProviderName %>" 
  SelectCommand="select distinct(region_cd) from mv_gauge_filter_dist where region_cd is not null">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Make note of the AppendDataBoundItems="true"...